# response.forEach(function(data) where response is a json bidimendional

Tags: javascript, php

Originally I had this:

In my php controller, I have a function that returns to an "url" var in Javascript (next):

```
/*$datos is an array like this:
array:2976 [
    0 => {#1827
        +"date": "2018-08-01"
        +"time": "00:00:00"
    }
    1 => {#1828
        +"date": "2018-08-01"
        +"time": "00:15:00"
    }]
*/

return response()->json($datos);
```

Then in Javascript, I use that `return` in `url`:

```
$.get(url, function(response){
    response.forEach(function(data){
    console.log(data);
```

console.log shows:

```
    {fecha: "2018-08-01", hora: "00:00:00"}
    {fecha: "2018-08-01", hora: "00:15:00"}
```

That's fine, but now, in php, I have to put two jsons together like this:

```
$datos = array(response()->json($datos_a), response()->json($datos_b));
return response()->json($datos);
```

$datos_a and $datos_b are like the first array of the example.

So, How can loop in the new response in javascript? I was expecting something like:

```
$.get(url, function(response){
    response["0"].forEach(function(data){
        console.log(data);}
    response["1"].forEach(function(data){
        console.log(data);}
```

Of course this is wrong, but I'm confused with all the arrays, json structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// PHP
$datos = [$datos_a, $datos_b];
return response()->json($datos);

// JS
$.get(url, function(response) {
  response.forEach(function(dataSet) {
    dataSet.forEach(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Basically, with this (from your attempt):

```
$datos = array(response()->json($datos_a), response()->json($datos_b));
return response()->json($datos);
```

... you JSON-encode the data twice (once for each data set, then one final time). You only need to encode the final value you want to return (output).

Comment: Thanks, I tried the array(datos_a, datos_b) but wasn't looping with 2 foreach.